# jQuery click function is not working inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

So here , i'm using an image as a button that's clickable using jQuery. 
Take a look at my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$("#hidebutton").hide();
$("#menubutton").hide();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".menubutt").click(function(){
    $("#mainbutton").fadeOut(500);
    $("#menubutton").delay(550).fadeIn(1500);
    $("#hidebutton").delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".expandbutt").click(function(){
    $("#mainbutton").delay(500).fadeIn();
    $("#hidebutton").fadeOut();
    $("#menubutton").fadeOut();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".next").click(function(){
        $(".previous").fadeOut();//for testing purpose
});
});
});
});
```

with the html

```
<div class="nextcont">
<img src="images/previous.png" class="previous">
<img src="images/next.png" class="next">
</div>
```

In some way , i can't click the (next) image

----EDIT----

I've changed the jquery syntax , with no luck i still cant click the (next) image.
I will post my code
HTML: http://pastebin.com/2vJbmZv7``
JQ  : http://pastebin.com/U24fD41s

Comment: I hope that you figure out the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wrong closing brackets.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$("#hidebutton").hide();
$("#menubutton").hide();
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".menubutt").click(function(){
$("#mainbutton").fadeOut(500);
$("#menubutton").delay(550).fadeIn(1500);
$("#hidebutton").delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".expandbutt").click(function(){
$("#mainbutton").delay(500).fadeIn();
$("#hidebutton").fadeOut();
$("#menubutton").fadeOut();
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(".previous").fadeOut();//for testing purpose
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".next").click(function(){
    $(".previous").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Try this it will work perfectly if your page has jquery library

Answer (score 0):

There was some syntax error .Corrected code here

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $("#hidebutton").hide();
    $("#menubutton").hide();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(".menubutt").click(function(){
        $("#mainbutton").fadeOut(500);
        $("#menubutton").delay(550).fadeIn(1500);
        $("#hidebutton").delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

    });
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $(".expandbutt").click(function(){
        $("#mainbutton").delay(500).fadeIn();
        $("#hidebutton").fadeOut();
        $("#menubutton").fadeOut();
    });
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(".next").click(function(){
            $(".previous").fadeOut();//for testing purpose
    });
    });
```